# Predict a nonlinear array based on 2 features with scalar values using XGBoost or equivalent

Tags: xgboost, non-linear-regression

So I have been looking at XGBoost as a place to start with this, however I am not sure the best way to accomplish what I want.

My data is set up something like this

[image: 1]

Where every value, whether it be input or output is numerical. The issue I'm facing is that I only have 3 input data points per several output data points.

I have seen that XGBoost has a multi-output regression method, however I am only really seeing it used to predict around 2 outputs per 1 input, whereas my data may have upwards of 50 output points needing to be predicted with only a handful of scalar input features.

I'd appreciate any ideas you may have.

For reference, I've been looking at mainly these two demos (they are the same idea just one is scikit and the other xgboost)

https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-output-regression-models-with-python/

https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/examples/multioutput_regression.html